# Serving static sites from S3 with nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I know that S3 can serve a simple index.html file if it's in the root of a bucket, but my need is to serve lots of simple static sites and S3 has a limit of 100 buckets per account, so I have to use nginx and some subdirectories (like http://foo.bar.com/test/index.html, the bucket is always foo.bar.com, that I mapped on the domain bar.com using a CNAME that points to foo.bar.com.s3.amazonaws.com).

These static sites should be accessible from subdomain.bar.com and serve directly the index.html file.

This is my nginx conf:

```
server {

        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
        listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        server_name *.bar.com;

        set $subdomain "";

        if ($host ~* "^(.+)\.bar\.com$") {
                set $subdomain $1;
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /$subdomain/index.html last;
                break;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://foo.bar.com/;
        }

}
```

I'm almost there :)
What happens now is that the index.html file is downloaded: I checked with curl and the content-type is octet/strem. I've tried to overwrite the header to text/html and succeeded, but I keep downloading the file.

I believe that my mistake is hardcoding index.html, the index instruction I give is sompletely redundant, I'm not able to make it work.

What I would like nginx to do is to receive test.bar.com, and serve (not download) the html file located in http://foo.bar.com.s3.amazonaws.com/test/index.html

Can someone help me?

TIA

Comment: Mime type is critical, not all http clients rely on file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with curl -- what kind of reply come from http://foo.bar.com/ ?

Pass correct `Content-type: text/html` when put your files to S3.

`s3put -t text/html ....` did the trick

Comment: You sir, seriously rock.

Comment: I have a question posted [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/538866/handling-multiple-server-blocks-in-nginx-configuration).Can you give your inputs on it?